# How to change text size of a checkbox list within an alert dialog

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I'm working on an alert dialog that has multiple checkboxes. How do I change the text size of the elements of the checkbox list? (I can change the size of the title and the buttons just fine)

```
boolean[] allBoolean = {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true};

AlertDialog.Builder prompt = new AlertDialog.Builder(Class.this);
prompt.setTitle("Title");
prompt.setMultiChoiceItems(all, allBoolean, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        allBoolean[which] = isChecked;
    }
});
prompt.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        //do nothing
    }
});
prompt.setPositiveButton("Select", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: You should go for custom dialog

Answer (score 0):

```
alertDialog.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = 150;
lp.height = 500;
lp.x=-170;
lp.y=100;
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually get access to the message's TextView pretty easily, and then change it's size. I tested with a bigger size, but you could use whatever size you want. The text will scroll nicely as it already does. The view's id is android.R.id.message :

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setTextSize(40);
```

This is probably a cleaner solution, though I'm not sure if there's a risk that the TextView could be null or not.

Comment: This would only change the text size of the message. It doesn't change the text size of the multiple choice elements.